# I tried to copy my Android Studio project and make another app by it, but it has problems with gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, copy

I refactored the original app and copied it. After that, I tried to open it and it says: should computer do gradle for me or manually? I chose that computer does job for me. After it started syncing gradle but an error occurred. 
On the sync part it said:

```
Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Computer\AndroidStudioProjects\IUSsystem\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

this is the folder where an error occured:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.IUSsystem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

here is the folder when it has shown the error. Im only using Android Studio for making my app, not eclipse.
Any help would be great, Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Remove line from the file in which error is occuring : "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new Android application in Android Studio via Gradle -- so that it already includes `com.android.application` and then adding your code in once it's already a successfully built project -- once it's built, start adding in your dependencies first and continue to check that it builds before adding in source code

Comment: @AK47 the thing is im using Android studio not eclipse :(

Comment: you must import the project rather open it.. remove the project you have opened (recommendation: delete them) and import it from the very beginning...The entire configuration of the project will be as per your environment after the build.

Comment: That process of me copying and pasting whole code will take around 6 hours from different xml files, etc

Comment: @SanketVekariya What do you mean by remove? Do you mean to delete my existing project, then what is the point of me making the copy if I'm gonna delete it

Comment: the ultimate thing is that the android studio will automatically set your Gradle versions based on the existence in your environment.. though you can change it manually with the versions available in your system...you should first identify the versions available in your system and change it accordingly...for example, I have the compiled SDK version available in my system is 28 then I will just replace it with the existing one... like so you should do it... the ultimate thing is to set it same as the available one in your system...